# Why is the joydev module enabled on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: drivers, server, joystick

I'm studying for my LPIC level 1 exam and was looking into modules in Ubuntu Server. I noticed that the "joydev" module was enabled on my server and upon running modinfo, realised it is a module to support Joystick devices. I just wondered why it would be there in a server installation? It's not a vital question but I was just curious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's showing up in `lsmod` output, then you have either a sound card with joystick device support, or your motherboard has an optional joystick port, and it is not disabled in the BIOS. Module loading depends on your hardware. All modules that are built from the kernel are shipped together, and will be available on the system, whether you have the hardware or not.